# Open SVG as a Google Drawing Programmatically

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an SVG generated on a webpage.  Is it possible to add a link that someone could click on to open the svg in google drawing without having to download it?  Ideally it would send the user here: https://docs.google.com/drawings

I have enabled Drive UI integration using https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk and I believe I have credentials.  I'm not sure how to get a file on Google Drive though & provide a link to a user.